# Alembic revision treats tables as columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic, sqlmodel

I'm having problem with alembic revision. When running `alembic revision --autogenerate`, I do receive corrupted schema. Two tables out of 6 are there and there rest is treated as columns. I'm running out of ideas what's wrong.

These are my models:

```
class SkillBase(SQLModel):
    id_skill: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    family: Family
    domain: Domain
    provider: str
    skill_name: str = Field(unique=True)
    skill_type: SkillType


# --- > TABLES


class DateCreation(SQLModel):
    date_creation: datetime = Field(
        default_factory=datetime.utcnow().date, nullable=False
    )


class Offer(ORM, DateCreation, table=True):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    id_offer: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    ext_id_offer: str
    link_offer: str
    offer_desc: str


class Skill(ORM, SkillBase, DateCreation, table=True):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    user_creation: str
    date_last_mod: datetime = Field(
        default_factory=datetime.utcnow().date, nullable=False
    )
    people: List["Person_skill"] = Relationship(back_populates="skill")


class Project(ORM, table=True):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    id_project: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    project_name: str
    start_date: datetime
    end_date: datetime
    owner: str
    cost_center: str
    people: List["Person"] = Relationship(back_populates="project")


class Person(ORM, table=True):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    id_person: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    current_id_project: int = Field(foreign_key="project.id_project")
    project: Optional[Project] = Relationship(back_populates="people")
    skills: List["Person_skill"] = Relationship(back_populates="person")


class Person_skill(ORM, table=True):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    id_person_skill: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    id_person: int = Field(foreign_key="person.id_person")
    person: Optional[Person] = Relationship(back_populates="skills")
    id_skill: int = Field(foreign_key="skill.id_skill")
    skill: Optional[Skill] = Relationship(back_populates="people")
    level_wod: int
    yoe: int
    certification: int
    training: int
    score: int


class Offer_skill(ORM, DateCreation, table=True):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    id_offer_skill: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    id_offer: int = Field(foreign_key="offer.id_offer")
    id_skill: int = Field(foreign_key="skill.id_skill")
```

`ORM` implements classmethod functions like update, delete etc.

Based on the above when running `alembic revision --autogenerate` I receive:

```
def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('offer_skill',
    sa.Column('date_creation', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('id_offer_skill', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('id_offer', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('id_skill', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id_offer'], ['offer.id_offer'], ),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id_skill'], ['skill.id_skill'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id_offer_skill')
    )
    op.create_table('person_skill',
    sa.Column('id_person_skill', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('id_person', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('id_skill', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('level_wod', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('yoe', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('certification', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('training', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('score', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id_person'], ['person.id_person'], ),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id_skill'], ['skill.id_skill'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id_person_skill')
    )
    op.drop_table('offerskill')
    op.drop_table('personskill')
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('date_creation', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('id_offer', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('ext_id_offer', sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.AutoString(), nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('link_offer', sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.AutoString(), nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('offer_desc', sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.AutoString(), nullable=False))
    op.drop_column('offer', 'offer_link')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'created')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'description')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'ext_offer_id')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'id')
    op.add_column('person', sa.Column('id_person', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    op.add_column('person', sa.Column('current_id_project', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    op.drop_constraint('person_first_name_key', 'person', type_='unique')
    op.drop_constraint('person_current_project_id_fkey', 'person', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'person', 'project', ['current_id_project'], ['id_project'])
    op.drop_column('person', 'id')
    op.drop_column('person', 'created')
    op.drop_column('person', 'current_project_id')
    op.add_column('project', sa.Column('id_project', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    op.drop_column('project', 'id')
    op.drop_column('project', 'created')
    op.add_column('skill', sa.Column('date_creation', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False))
    op.add_column('skill', sa.Column('id_skill', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    op.drop_column('skill', 'id')
    op.drop_column('skill', 'created')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('skill', sa.Column('created', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('skill', sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False))
    op.drop_column('skill', 'id_skill')
    op.drop_column('skill', 'date_creation')
    op.add_column('project', sa.Column('created', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('project', sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False))
    op.drop_column('project', 'id_project')
    op.add_column('person', sa.Column('current_project_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('person', sa.Column('created', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('person', sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False))
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'person', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_foreign_key('person_current_project_id_fkey', 'person', 'project', ['current_project_id'], ['id'])
    op.create_unique_constraint('person_first_name_key', 'person', ['first_name'])
    op.drop_column('person', 'current_id_project')
    op.drop_column('person', 'id_person')
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('ext_offer_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('description', sa.VARCHAR(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('created', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('offer', sa.Column('offer_link', sa.VARCHAR(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False))
    op.drop_column('offer', 'offer_desc')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'link_offer')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'ext_id_offer')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'id_offer')
    op.drop_column('offer', 'date_creation')
    op.create_table('personskill',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('person_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('skill_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('wod_level', postgresql.ENUM('BEGINNER', 'MEDIUM', 'ADVANCED', name='wodlevel'), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('yoe', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('certification', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('training', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('score', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['person_id'], ['person.id'], name='personskill_person_id_fkey'),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['skill_id'], ['skill.id'], name='personskill_skill_id_fkey'),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='personskill_pkey')
    )
    op.create_table('offerskill',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('offer_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('skill_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['offer_id'], ['offer.id'], name='offerskill_offer_id_fkey'),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['skill_id'], ['skill.id'], name='offerskill_skill_id_fkey'),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='offerskill_pkey')
    )
    op.drop_table('person_skill')
    op.drop_table('offer_skill')
```

As you can see it's totally wrong... Appreciate any help.